# curve smoothing in c++

Tags: c++, math, smoothing

I want to smooth a curve and i don't know what approach to follow , The pattern are stored in a vector .

```
class Point2D
    {
    public:
        double x, y;
        Point2D() 
        {
            this->x=0; 
            this->y=0;
        }
        Point2D(double x, double y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
           }

vector<Point2D> vec1;
```

vec1 :

```
         *
       *    *

    .        .
   .           . 
  .              .
 .                 .
.                    .    .
                        .
```

Expected pattern after smoothing:

```
         *
       *    *
     .        .

   .             . 
  .                .
 .                  .
.                    .    .
                        .
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing, the Savitzky-Golay might be what you're looking for

Comment: really generic question, many approach are compatible with your general issue, for example you can also adopt Bezier curve http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Laplacian smoothing.  Except for the points you want to remain fixed (e.g. the stars in your diagram), set each point to the average of its immediate neighbors. Repeat once or twice, depending  on how much smoothing you want.

Comment: Is there any source code available ? I can;t seem to find it .

Comment: @rajat, it's not hard to write your own.  Average of two points `p`,`q` is `(p+q)/2`.

Comment: i wrote my own , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973255/algorithm-for-smoothing . I don't know what it's called by i wrote what makes sense to me , and it seems to be working fine .

Comment: @rajat, I've edited my answer to specify averaging immediate neighbors.  You appear to be using multiple neighbours.  That's fine if you are getting results you want, but it's not what I thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a vague question but if you want to smooth out a set of data you can have a look into [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).

It is a link for polynomial regression. You can then use your fitted polynomial to generate smooth points on the curve.

Hope this helps.