# Algorithm for smoothing

Tags: c++, algorithm, filter, signal-processing

I wrote this code for smoothing of a curve .
It takes 5 points next to a point and adds them and averages it .

```
/* Smoothing */
void smoothing(vector<Point2D> &a)
{
    //How many neighbours to smooth
    int NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS=10;
    vector<Point2D> tmp=a;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {

        if(i+NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS+1<a.size())
        {
            for(int j=1;j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;j++)
            {
                a.at(i).x+=a.at(i+j).x;
                a.at(i).y+=a.at(i+j).y;
            }
            a.at(i).x/=NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;
            a.at(i).y/=NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;

        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=1;j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;j++)
            {
                a.at(i).x+=tmp.at(i-j).x;
                a.at(i).y+=tmp.at(i-j).y;
            }
            a.at(i).x/=NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;
            a.at(i).y/=NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;
        }

    }

}
```

But i get very high values for each point, instead of the similar values to the previous point . The shape is maximized a lot , what is going wrong in this algorithm ?

Comment: Use `+=` and `/=` it makes your code more readable (and has less calls to `at(i)`).

Comment: What happens if you feed it simple data, where the results are predictable, and you debug it?

Comment: j is zero-based, so in your inner loops you are not smoothing with ]i, i+NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS], but with [i, i+NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS]

Comment: Bear in mind that in the else clause you are accessing elements that were already altered by your smoothing algorithm! Also note that averaging a point with its neighbors you have to divide the sum by `1 + NO_OF_NEIGHBORS`, as the point itself is contained within this sum.

Comment: @Nobody i know  that i am accessing the already altered points , there there a better alternative to include the boundary condition ?

Comment: You could use a copy of the original vector to read from.

Comment: @Nobody Does the last edit make everything ok ? Do i still have to divide by 1+NO_OF_NEIGHBORS ? .I know it's smoothing based on NO_OF_NEIGHBORS-1 but that's ok .

Comment: You forgot to use `tmp` in the `if` clause and the `+ 1` in the condition seems a bit weird. The division by `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` or `1 + NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` is just matter of understanding. You simply need to know how many points are in the sum that get averaged. In your edited example `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` (without `+ 1`) is the correct divisor.

Comment: i think it's not important to use tmp in if , because it is not assessing the elements that are already smooth .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in following block:

```
            for(int j=0;j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;j++)
            {
                a.at(i).x=a.at(i).x+a.at(i+j).x;
                a.at(i).y=a.at(i).y+a.at(i+j).y;
            }
```

for each neighbour you add a.at(i)'s x and y respectively to neighbour values.

i understand correctly, it should be something like this.

```
            for(int j=0;j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;j++)
            {
                a.at(i).x += a.at(i+j+1).x
                a.at(i).y += a.at(i+j+1).y
            }
```

Comment: When using this change `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` will be one more than the actual number of neighbors used.

Comment: right, condition should be j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS+1, to be more clear, j should start from 0, a.at(i+j) shoud be a.at(i+j+1).

Comment: The variable is named `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` meaning the number of neighbors to smooth with. Given your corrected loop `j` will have `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS - 1` different values, meaning that `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS - 1` neighbors will be smoothed, which is a bit counter intuitive to the name.

Answer (score 10):

What it looks like you have here is a bass-ackwards implementation of a finite impulse response (FIR) filter that implements a [boxcar window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Rectangular_window). Thinking about the problem in terms of DSP, you need to filter your incoming `vector` with `NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS` equal FIR coefficients that each have a value of `1/NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS`. It is normally best to use an established algorithm rather than reinvent the wheel.

Here is a pretty scruffy implementation that I hammered out quickly that filters doubles. You can easily modify this to filter your data type. The demo shows filtering of a few cycles of a rising saw function (0,.25,.5,1) just for demonstration purposes. It compiles, so you can play with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class boxFIR
{
    int numCoeffs; //MUST be > 0
    vector<double> b; //Filter coefficients
    vector<double> m; //Filter memories

public:
    boxFIR(int _numCoeffs) :
    numCoeffs(_numCoeffs)
    {
        if (numCoeffs<1)
            numCoeffs = 1; //Must be > 0 or bad stuff happens

        double val = 1./numCoeffs;
        for (int ii=0; ii<numCoeffs; ++ii) {
            b.push_back(val);
            m.push_back(0.);
        }
    }    

    void filter(vector<double> &a)
    {
        double output;

        for (int nn=0; nn<a.size(); ++nn)
        {
            //Apply smoothing filter to signal
            output = 0;
            m[0] = a[nn];
            for (int ii=0; ii<numCoeffs; ++ii) {
                output+=b[ii]*m[ii];
            }

            //Reshuffle memories
            for (int ii = numCoeffs-1; ii!=0; --ii) {
                m[ii] = m[ii-1];
            }                        
            a[nn] = output;
        }
    }


};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boxFIR box(1); //If this is 1, then no filtering happens, use bigger ints for more smoothing

    //Make a rising saw function for demo
    vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(0.); a.push_back(0.25); a.push_back(0.5); a.push_back(0.75); a.push_back(1.);
    a.push_back(0.); a.push_back(0.25); a.push_back(0.5); a.push_back(0.75); a.push_back(1.);
    a.push_back(0.); a.push_back(0.25); a.push_back(0.5); a.push_back(0.75); a.push_back(1.);
    a.push_back(0.); a.push_back(0.25); a.push_back(0.5); a.push_back(0.75); a.push_back(1.);

    box.filter(a);

    for (int nn=0; nn<a.size(); ++nn)
    {
        cout << a[nn] << endl;
    }
}
```

Up the number of filter coefficients using this line to see a progressively more smoothed output. With just 1 filter coefficient, there is no smoothing.

```
boxFIR box(1);
```

The code is flexible enough that you can even change the window shape if you like. Do this by modifying the coefficients defined in the constructor.

Note: This will give a slightly different output to your implementation as this is a causal filter (only depends on current sample and previous samples). Your implementation is not causal as it looks ahead in time at future samples to make the average, and that is why you need the conditional statements for the situation where you are near the end of your vector. If you want output like what you are attempting to do with your filter using this algorithm, run the your vector through this algorithm in reverse (This works fine so long as the window function is symmetrical). That way you can get similar output without the nasty conditional part of algorithm.

Comment: I had no idea about the FIR Filter , i just wanted to smooth the points .Will the time domain implementations of FIR filters better than this algorithm ?

Comment: @rajat Absolutely, `if` statements in the middle of a filtering function are nasty as you have to have a separate algorithm for your boundaries. See my edits

Comment: YEY. Someone gave this a +1. This IS the optimum solution. Grumble grumble grumble.

Comment: A reverse pass could be useful to prevent phase distortion (in that case it's a zero-phase distortion filter).

Answer (score 3):

Filtering is good for 'memory' smoothing. This is the reverse pass for the [learnvst's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973856/1305053) answer, to prevent [phase distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_distortion):

```
for (int i = a.size(); i > 0; --i)
{
    // Apply smoothing filter to signal
    output = 0;
    m[m.size() - 1] = a[i - 1];

    for (int j = numCoeffs; j > 0; --j) 
        output += b[j - 1] * m[j - 1];

    // Reshuffle memories
    for (int j = 0; j != numCoeffs; ++j) 
        m[j] = m[j + 1];

    a[i - 1] = output;
}
```

More about zero-phase distortion FIR filter in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html

Answer (score 1):

The current-value of the point is used twice: once because you use `+=` and once if `y==0`. So you are building the sum of eg 6 points but only dividing by 5. This problem is in both the IF and ELSE case. Also: you should check that the vector is long enough otherwise your ELSE-case will read at negative indices.

Following is not a problem in itself but just a thought: Have you considered to use an algorithm that only touches every point twice?: You can store a temporary x-y-value (initialized to be identical to the first point), then as you visit each point you just add the new point in and subtract the very-oldest point if it is further than your `NEIGHBOURS` back. You keep this "running sum" updated for every point and store this value divided by the `NEIGHBOURS`-number into the new point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about checking vector length.I am having a hard time understand the alternative algorithm . Can you explain it in the terms of pseudo code ?

Comment: Ohk,understood thanks :) . the time complexity is not a worry in my problem as i have a vector with only 128 points .

Answer (score 1):

You make addition with point itself when you need to take neighbor points - just offset index by 1:

```
for(int j=0;j<NO_OF_NEIGHBOURS;j++)
 {
    a.at(i).x += a.at(i+j+1).x
    a.at(i).y += a.at(i+j+1).y
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
for (i = 0; i < lenInput; i++)
{
    float x = 0;
    for (int j = -neighbours; j <= neighbours; j++)
    {
        x += input[(i + j <= 0) || (i + j >= lenInput) ? i : i + j];
    }
    output[i] = x / (neighbours * 2 + 1);
}
```